# PDF: standard format for highlights?

Tags: pdf

Many PDF viewers (for example apple's Preview) allow one to select text to highlight like a regular yellow marker highlighter.  These highlights can then be saved into the PDF file and reopened in other viewer apps.

Is there a standard part of the de facto PDF specification that defines highlights?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PDF standard (section 3.6.2 of version 1.7, according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3449944/whats-needed-to-handle-annotation-viewing-in-a-pdf/3450243#3450243)) deals with annotations, this is what PDF viewer use to save highlights

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple ways to achieve highlights - you can use shapes (rectangles) with transparency or use the highlight annotation type ([12.5.6.10 Text Markup Annotations](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf#page=411)).

See [Adobe's PDF Spec](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf).

Comment: Are there any Android PDF viewers that respect this spec? I'm looking for a PDF annotator, but not too keen on getting locked into a particular PDF noting-adding app.